# Citations in Latex not working using biber backend and biblatex

Tags: latex, bibliography, citations, biblatex

I am working on a presentation and for some reason, none of my citations are working. I have created presentations with Latex before and never encountered this problem.

The following is a minimal example which is not working:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\bibliography{literatur.bib}
%\addbibresource{common/literatur.bib}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \cite{test_citation}
    \end{frame}
    
    \nocite{*}
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=.85]{Bibliography}
        \printbibliography
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

During compilation, I get the following messages:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 21.10)
The top-level auxiliary file: document.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file document.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file document.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file document.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

`literatur.bib` lies on the same level as `document.tex` and contains the following text:

```
@article{test_citation,
    author="Author, Dummy",
    title="Dummy citation",
    year="2022"
}
```

I suspect that something is wrong with my biblatex installation, because even making the problem as simple as possible, the bibliography contains not a single entry in spite of the `\nocite{*}` command.

Comment: If you wnat to use the biber backend, you have to use biber and not bibtex. Your error message shows you are using bibtex

Comment: Also `\bibliography{...}` is a bibtex command. If you are using biblatex, you should use `\addbibressource{...}`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you! It had been so long since I last worked with LaTeX it seems I forgot to set Texstudio to use Biber for compilation of the bibliography. Now that I did, it's working.

Comment: You're welcome! Instead of worrying yourself about such details, I would simply use latexmk to compile the document. This will automatically detect the appropriate bibliography tools, the number of necessary tex runs etc.